# Simple Looping file reading in folder does not run at all

Tags: excel, vba

I am having some issue even running this simple code. Can anyone shine a light?

```
Sub GetFilest()
    Dim file As String
    file = Dir("\ttsnas02\user_mdocs$\tdf8273\Documents\Rob\External supplier timesheet\CSV Supplier Main\Inbox folder\*.xlsm")

    Dim row As Integer
    row = 1

    Do While file <> ""
        Cells(row, 1) = file
        row = row + 1
        file = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Should `"\ttsnas02\....` be `"\\ttsnas02\....`?  (It looks more like it is meant to be a UNC than a path hanging from the root directory of the current drive.)

Comment: yes thankyou that's exactly what it was

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub GetFilest()
Dim file As String
file = Dir("\ttsnas02\user_mdocs$\tdf8273\Documents\Rob\External supplier timesheet\CSV Supplier Main\Inbox folder\*.xlsm")

Dim row As Integer
row = 1

    Do While file <> ""
    Cells(row, 1) = file
    row = row + 1
    'try to remove code below (why you reassign file variabel with Dir() function..?)
    'file = Dir()

Loop

End Sub
```